# How Can I remove the Commas if more than on Comma(,)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am Developing sample Application.

In this List view I have a small Issue: The Address Page Getting More Commas.

If the Address not having that showing , like this Page Getting more Commas. But I have only one Comma, if more than 1  comma how can we reduce.

[image]

Here this my Code:

```
 var finalset = n;
                  console.log(finalset)
                  address_line1=finalset[0]
                  address_line2=finalset[1]
                  address_line3=finalset[2]
                  address_line4=finalset[3]
                  address_locality=finalset[4]
                  address_city=finalset[5]
                  address_country=finalset[6]
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.updatedFunction.bind(this, n)}>
      <View style={styles.searchAddressView}>
            <Text style={styles.searchText}>{finalset}</Text>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'25 Derby Road, , , Nottingham, Nottinghamshire'.replace(/(,\s+)+/g, ', ')
```

results in `25 Derby Road, Nottingham, Nottinghamshire`

Explanation: this will replace all repeating sequences that have comma and 1 or more whitespace with only one ", ".

Comment: Thanks a Lot It's Working

Comment: mark it as answer if it works and upvote if it helped you! :)

Comment: Thanks @TSvetan , But In this When i was select one Address Line like 
25 Derby Road, , , Nottingham, Nottinghamshire,
It's I am giving {"/n"} this each  Address line. If  some one Address miss Showing gap Like this 

25 Derby Road
                          between showing space
Nottingham, 
Nottinghamshire

Comment: @Lavaraju sorry, I can't understand. You are adding new line at the end of each address line, and what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Ans from Tsvetan is good , but if space with comma is different in different situation then you can also use this type of solution.

```
$.map('25 Derby Road, , , Nottingham, Nottinghamshire'.split(','),$.trim).filter(Boolean).join(',')
```

Comment: why we are using map

Comment: I didn't Understood Can u explain this

Comment: Its jquery map function , it is used to apply something to all the element of array. So in this case if some of your  string part is like " ABC " with the space in start or end , we will trim and get the proper value as "ABC" . and then after `filter(Boolean)` will remove all empty element from array. And join will join the element with provided delimiter.